# Extract solutions in an interval for a trigonometric equation

Tags: equation-solving, syntax

Consider the solution

```
x1 = x /. Solve[{Cos[x] + Sin[x] == 0}, x]
```

The output is a conditional expression or, with `//Normal`, a shorter, general, answer with all solutions.

How do I extract all solutions, between $a$ and $b$, say $0 < x < 2\pi$?

So far I have been forced to evaluate

```
sol1 = x1[[2]] /. C[1] -> 0
```

for various selections of the "solution branches" and setting `C[1]` to different numerical values, all which seems an incorrect way of doing it efficiently. TIA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tell Mathematica your constraint `0 <= x <= 2 Pi`:

```
Solve[{Cos[x] + Sin[x] == 0, 0 <= x <= 2 Pi}, x]
(*{{x -> 2 π + 2 ArcTan[1 - Sqrt[2]]}, {x -> 2 ArcTan[1 + Sqrt[2]]}}*)    

FullSimplify[%]
(*{{x -> (7 π)/4}, {x -> (3 π)/4}}*)
```

Comment: I tried that, but got the somewhat "long-ish" answer that you quote which seems a bit overworked, when there is a much simpler, fractional, form.

Comment: Add ``FullSimplify` (see my modified answer)!